# Getting liquibase.exception.CustomChangeException on running Java code changeset in liquibase

Tags: java, liquibase

I am running Java code changeset in liquibase. But I am facing this issue where I am getting ClassNotFoundException.I did some searching around but could not find anything helpful. Alltough some research at  [this link](http://forum.liquibase.org/topic/customsqlchange-and-classnotfoundexception)  was useful. I am using liquibase-core-2.0.1.

Below is my Changeset

```
<changeSet id="111" author="myname" >
        <customChange class="com.example.CreateTableTask">
        </customChange>
</changeSet>
```

Below is my java class

```
public class CreateTableTask implements CustomTaskChange
{
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CreateTableTask.class.getName());
    @Override
    public void execute(Database database) throws CustomChangeException
    {
        System.out.print("testsomestring");
        try
        {
            JdbcConnection databaseConnection = (JdbcConnection) database.getConnection();
            log.info("testsomestring");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new CustomChangeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getConfirmationMessage()
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws SetupException
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void setFileOpener(ResourceAccessor resourceAccessor)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public ValidationErrors validate(Database database)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Below is the exception I am getting

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.CreateTableTask
>   liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: Invalid Migration File:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.CreateTableTask
>           at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parse(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:132)
>           at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:107)
>           at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.doMigration(Main.java:825)
>           at liquibase.integration.commandline.Main.main(Main.java:134) Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.example.CreateTableTask liquibase.exception.CustomChangeException:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.CreateTableTask
>           at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXHandler.startElement(XMLChangeLogSAXHandler.java:478)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:509)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:749)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:379)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2786)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:117)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
>           at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:648)
>           at liquibase.parser.core.xml.XMLChangeLogSAXParser.parse(XMLChangeLogSAXParser.java:98)

Comment: What command did you use to start Liquibase, and where is the jar file containing your custom code? The way that it should work is that Liquibase will scan the classpath for the class mentioned. You can give liquibase.bat (or liquibase.sh) an argument to specify a classpath, or Liquibase will look in its lib directory by default, if I recall correctly. 

That is a very old version of Liquibase, so if you can upgrade you probably should.

Comment: Thanks  @SteveDonie .. **Update** is tjhe command I am using for liquibase.. what was missing is **argument to specify a classpath** .. Its resolved now.. Can you place the comment as answer I would accept it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What command did you use to start Liquibase, and where is the jar file containing your custom code?

The way that it should work is that Liquibase will scan the classpath for the class mentioned. You can give liquibase.bat (or liquibase.sh) an argument to specify a classpath, or Liquibase will look in its lib directory by default, if I recall correctly.